# Get Unique ID of one attachment with GMAIL API

Tags: gmail-api

I am working with the new GMail API. My goal is to get a list of all of attachments of each email. It is done and working.

Now, I would like to get the direct link to open in a new window each attachment when user clicks on each attachment. How can I get that "ID"?

This is what I do:

```
Message message = service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).execute();
        List<MessagePart> parts = message.getPayload().getParts();
        for (MessagePart part : parts) {
          if (part.getFilename() != null && part.getFilename().length() > 0) {
            String filename = part.getFilename();
            String attId = part.getBody().getAttachmentId(); // It isn't ID that Im looking for.
```

I use JAVA.

Thank you,
Diego.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there does seem to be a way to have the user directly download an attachment from gmail's servers without the file passing through our severs. Found it here:

https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/issues/134#issuecomment-69447858

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=att&th={message_id}&attid=0.{atachment_index}&disp=safe&zw
```

> attachmment_index is just the index of the attachment. If there are 3 attachments and you want to get the 3rd file, the index value will be 3. This URL is a 302 header that acts like a link shortener for the download file. Opening this link will lead you to the attachment data

There's a mention of an `ik` value, which I don't know what it's for, but it seems to work even without that.

@aloo

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I would not try to rely on the attachment id, but rather download the raw content of the attachment on your server and display it to the user.

It should not be too complicated, you juste need to parse the content of [the `data` field](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments). You can do this using Java's Mime library. Then you copy the content into your Servlet's `OutputStream`.

Comment: Your idea is great but it is not what I am looking for. I don't want to show the attachment, I want to edit it. I will try to work on this.

Comment: An idea would be to upload it on GDrive and allow the user to open it in Google Drive. That way the user will be allowed to choose his/her app of preference to edit the document.

Comment: Well, this idea is what we're using. We have all these attachments on GDrive and we can open them on GDrive editor. I was using 'javamail' to get the EMAIL_ID and ATTACHMENT_ID to store my attachments but with this API, I don't have the same values...

Comment: what if you wanted the client user to download the file directly without it passing through your servers, is there a directly accessible public URL?

Comment: A solution would be to use JavaScript to have the user's browser download the attachment and transfer it to drive. That way it never goes through your servers. But it requires the user to be on your webpage during that phase.